# Encoding an array of bytes similar to Base64, but with arbitrary radix

Tags: c#, algorithm, encoding, base64, decode

Does the procedure have a name, where you take a stream of 8-bit bytes and slice them into n-bit snippets stored in 8-bit containers?

The idea is very similar to Base64 encoding, where you split the stream of 1's and 0's into 6-bit chunks (instead of 8), meaning each chunk can have a decimal value of 0 - 63, each of which is assigned a unique human-readable character. In my case, I'm not looking to assign each chunk a specific character.

For example, the input 8-bit bytes:

```
11100101 01101100 01010011 00001100 11000000 10111101
```

become the 6-bit snippets:

```
111001 010110 110001 010011 000011 001100 000010 111101
```

which are subsequently stored as:

```
00111001 00010110 00110001 00010011 00000011 00001100 00000010 00111101
```

or, optionally, with an offset of 1 bit:

```
01110010 00101100 01100010 00100110 00000110 00011000 00000100 01111010
```

or and offset of 2 bits:

```
11100100 01011000 11000100 01001100 00001100 00110000 00001000 11110100
```

I was looking to write an algorithm in C# to encode a byte array to an arbitrary length with arbitrary offset, and another algorithm to convert it back again.

After quite a lot of headache, I thought I had successfully written the forward algorithm to encode an array of bytes. It worked for all my test cases, but when started writing the reverse algorithm I realised the whole problem was a lot more complicated than I thought it would be, and, in fact, my forward algorithm didn't work where n < 4.

I wanted to write the algorithms with bitwise operators, which is the more proper and elegant solution. The other way would have been to dump the byte array as a long string of 1's and 0's to slice, but that would have been much, much slower.

Here is my forward algorithm that works for cases where n >= 4:

```
public static byte[] EncodeForward(byte[] input, int n, int offset = 0)
{
    byte[] output = new byte[(int)Math.Ceiling(input.Length * 8.0 / n)];

    output[0] = (byte)(input[0] >> (8 - n));

    int p = 1;
    int r = 8 - n;

    for (int i = 1; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        output[p++] = (byte)((byte)((byte)(input[i - 1] << (8 - r)) | (byte)(input[i] >> r)) >> (8 - n - offset));

        if ((r += (8 - n)) == n)
        {
            output[p++] = (byte)(input[i] & (byte)(0xFF >> (8 - n)));
            r = 0;
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

I originally conceived it for just the case of n = 7, so each output byte would be composed by parts of at most 7 input bytes. However in the case where n < 4, each output byte would be composed by up to, I think, ceil(8/n) input bytes, so the process is a little more complex than above.

I was hoping to write the forward and reverse algorithms myself, but, honestly, after all this time debugging and testing what I've written and now finding this approach will never work for n < 4, I'm just looking for something that works. These two algorithms are just a very small piece of the project I'm working on.

Does this encoding/decoding procedure have a name, and is there either a built-in way to do it in C# or is there a library that will do it?

Comment: I have production code that does 5 bit in C++, would that do? We use it to store binary values into database char fields.

Comment: At the moment I need 7 bits. I just want to put special control characters in amongst arbitrary data, hence why I need a magic bit. But I figured if I'm going to write code that does it for 7 bits, then I may as well right general functions that handle arbitrary bits.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. You just need and intermediate 16-bit buffer and an unprocessed bits counter. Disclaimer: I don't know C#. The (pseudo) code below is written with C in mind; you may need some tweaking.

For encoding,

```
    uint16_t mask = 0xffff << (16 - width);

    uint16_t buffer = (input[0] << 8) | uint[1];
    i += 2;

    int remaining = 16;

    while (i < input.Length) {
        while (remaining >= width) {
            output[p++] = (buffer & mask) >> (16 - width);
            buffer <<= width;
            remaining -= width;
        }
        // Refill the buffer. Since it is 16-bit wide there is a room
        // for an _entire_ input byte.
        buffer |= input[i++] << (8 - remaining);
        remaining += 8;
   }
   emit_remaining_bits(buffer, remaining);
```

For decoding:

```
   uint16_t buffer = 0;
   int remaining = 16;
   while (i < input.Length) {
       while (remaining > 8) {
           buffer |= input[i++] << (remaining - width);
           remaining += width;
       }
       output[p++] = (buffer >> 8) & 0x00ff;
       buffer <<= 8;
       remaining += 8;
   }
```